# How to create a Broadband connection (pppoeconf) on my Android phone?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, networking, internet

I have Broadband connection at home, and from my PC running Linux, I use the **pppoeconf** command to connect to internet, that in turn asks me for the username and password both provided by my ISP (BSNL).

### Is there a way to create a broadband connection on my android phone?

<sup>**PS:** I'm currently using Android 2.2 (Froyo), and I don't wanna setup a proxy connection on my machine.</sup>

Comment: Are you able to connect a Wifi router to your broadband connection? That would be the normal way to share a broadband connection to a phone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[WIFI PPPOE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cnddu.wifipppoe) by [cnDDU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=cnDDU) is an app that allows you to make a PPPoE connection from your phone over a wireless connection:

> ...main purpose is for user
>   to make PPPOE connection via WIFI, e.g. dialing through ADSL Modem
>   with user name and password provided by some internet ISPs. This app
>   makes the Android devices be able to connect to Internet directly via
>   PPPOE dialing through WIFI, and no need for another WIFI Router any
>   more.

Note that a rooted phone with Busybox installed is required to use this app.

There are also a number of other [similar apps available in the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pppoe&c=apps) now, some free, some not. They all currently seem to require a rooted phone.

*(answer rescued from deletions)*

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://www.junefabrics.com/android/download.php. You need to install the app on your phone and on your laptop. Works with windows.