# How to connect Android phone to a Wifi network using PPPoE?

Tags: wi-fi, pppoe

I have an ISP at home, which provides me with a PPPoE connection. My router supports that and I've configured it to autoconnect periodically, so I don't have to type my username and password each time.

When I connect to the Wireless router from the PC, I have internet and everything works fine. However, when I do so using my Android phone, there's no internet connection on the phone. It connects to the router, but I cannot open any web page.

How can I enable internet access from such an ISP on my phone? Is it something in the router setup? The router is [Linksys WRT54GL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series#WRT54GL).

Comment: Duplicate? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9109/create-broadband-connectionpppoeconf-on-android

Answer (score 1):

There is an app that enables it (aptly called [WIFI PPPOE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cnddu.wifipppoe)), but it requires you to root your phone. PPPoE is not natively supported in the Android SDK.

Comment: Is this the only solution?

Comment: @Slavo Short of personally coding support into Android, yes. A non-root user doesn't have the permissions necessary to add that level/type of functionality. You could also push for the feature in the [Android forums](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=pppoe&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Owner+Summary+Stars&cells=tiles), but that's not an immediate fix to your problem.

Comment: I don't think that the OPs problem is that he want's to do PPPoE with Android. For some reasons OPs Android device just doesn't get internet connectivity when connected to the users router (which does PPPoE).

Comment: @Flow. Yes, exactly. Is there a way to make the router handle the PPPoE and hide it from Android?

Comment: That is what a home router basically does: Handling the upstream connection (in this case via PPPoE) and NATing this connection to it's clients.

Comment: I agree with @Flow, I think you're looking at a router config issue.