# How do I connect to PPPoE-based broadband on Android-x86 using ethernet?

Tags: internet, android-x86, ethernet, pppoe

I have installed Phoenix OS on my laptop. I don't connect to the internet with a WiFi router, but with a direct Ethernet port.

I found [How to connect Android phone to a Wifi network using PPPoE?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35678/44325) but it did not work out for me as mine is not a WiFi PPPoE issue.

How do I connect my Android installation to this PPPoE broadband?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know username and password to connect to the Internet using Ethernet port if you are using an Ethernet modem which is not configured.
Ask your ISP for the username and password.

Comment: Ok, I have the username and the password provided by my ISP. But Phoenix OS does not support DSL based internet, It only has WiFi. But it would work if my ISP automatically assigned IP address using a DHCP server.